# Delay windows phone 8 progress-bar appearance

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to delay appearance of progressbar in Windows Phone 8 application for 2 sec.
So when I call webservice if I don't receive response after 2 sec progress-bar should appear.

I have implemented code with *DispatcherTimer* but it does not seams to work as expected.
This variable is binded to *IsEnabled* and *IsVisible* of ProgressBar control.
Problem is that this code works randomly and not after 2 sec.When I increase timer for 20 sec progress-bar is still appearing even every response is bellow 1 sec.

```
 private bool _isProgressBarLoading;
    public bool IsProgressBarLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return _isProgressBarLoading;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isProgressBarLoading != value)
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000) };
                    timer.Tick += delegate
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                        _isProgressBarLoading = true;
                    };
                    timer.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    _isProgressBarLoading = false;
                }
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressBarLoading);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [different Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operating on separate thread:

```
System.Threading.Timer myTimer = null;
private bool _isProgressBarLoading = false;
public bool IsProgressBarLoading
{
    get { return _isProgressBarLoading; }
    set
    {
       if (_isProgressBarLoading != value)
       {
           if (value)
           {
                if (myTimer == null)
                {
                   myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, 3000, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
                else myTimer.Change(3000, Timeout.Infinite);
                // it should also work if you create new timer every time, but I think it's
                // more suitable to use one
           }
           else
           {
                _isProgressBarLoading = false;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressBarLoading);
           }
       }
    }
}

private void Callback(object state)
{
   Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
       _isProgressBarLoading = true;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressBarLoading);
    });
}
```

`DispatcherTimer` is working on the Main thread, I think it will be better to use other Thread.

---

And as for your code it should work if it looks like this - notify when you change the value:

```
if (value)
{
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000) };
    timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        timer.Stop();
        _isProgressBarLoading = true;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressBarLoading);
    };
    timer.Start();
}
else
{
    _isProgressBarLoading = false;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressBarLoading);
}
```

Comment: @RadenkoZec Once adain I've looked at your code and noticed why it probably hadn't worked - see my edit. On the other hand I think the first version is better ;)

Comment: I have tried to change only NotifyOfPropertyChange in delegate but again it did not worked. However your code with System.Threading.Timer with slight change works as expected.

Comment: @RadenkoZec I've tried this only on simple one button example, and it worked, but of course it depends on the App. Nevertheless I'm glad I've helped to find you a solution. Good luck